# Error in constructing Graphql schema and resolvers in deployment of Next.js app on Vercel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, next.js, vercel

I am using graphql-tools to merge Types and Schemas. My graphql server runs on the end point api/graphql

```
import { mergeTypeDefs, mergeResolvers } from "@graphql-tools/merge";
import { loadFilesSync } from "@graphql-tools/load-files";
import path from "path";

const typesArray = loadFilesSync(path.join(process.cwd(), "./**/*.graphql"));

export const types = mergeTypeDefs(typesArray);

const resolversArray = loadFilesSync(
  path.join(process.cwd(), "./**/*.resolvers.*")
);

export const resolvers = mergeResolvers(resolversArray);
```

The graphql endpoint works locally, however upon deployment to Vercel, I get the following error with Serverless Function when an API call is made to api/graphql

```
ERROR   Unhandled error during request: Error: Query root type must be provided.
    at assertValidSchema (/var/task/node_modules/graphql/type/validate.js:69:11)
    at assertValidExecutionArguments (/var/task/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:150:35)
    at executeImpl (/var/task/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:98:3)
    at Object.execute (/var/task/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:60:63)
    at Object.generateSchemaHash (/var/task/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/utils/schemaHash.js:15:32)
    at ApolloServer.generateSchemaDerivedData (/var/task/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:269:41)
    at new ApolloServerBase (/var/task/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:161:38)
    at new ApolloServer (/var/task/node_modules/apollo-server-micro/dist/ApolloServer.js:18:1)
    at Module.dCYn (/var/task/.next/serverless/pages/api/graphql.js:490:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/.next/serverless/pages/api/graphql.js:23:31)
    at Module.GfcW (/var/task/.next/serverless/pages/api/graphql.js:251:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/.next/serverless/pages/api/graphql.js:23:31)
    at /var/task/.next/serverless/pages/api/graphql.js:91:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/.next/serverless/pages/api/graphql.js:94:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
```

I believe it has to do with a mess up in the path for loadFilesSync. I tried replacing process.cwd() with __dirname, but it didn't work. I pretty much have scoured through every single resource on the internet but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.